# I want to send an message from my Android Watch to my Android Phone. Other way around is working

Tags: android, mobile, google-api, watch

I want to send an message to my phone on the moment I start an app on my watch.
I can't get this to work. The other way around is working every time.

Mobile manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="marcokreeft.domotica">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name=".ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />-->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/message_path" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Watch manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="marcokreeft.domotica">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name=".ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />-->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/message_path" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Mobile listenerservice:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals("/message_path")) {
            final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message path received on watch is: " + messageEvent.getPath());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message received on watch is: " + message);
        }
        else {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Wear mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleApiClient googleClient;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Build a new GoogleApiClient for the Wearable API
        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
    }

    // Connect to the data layer when the Activity starts
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleClient.connect();
    }

    // Send a message when the data layer connection is successful.
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String message = "Hello mobile\n Via the data layer";
        //Requires a new thread to avoid blocking the UI
        new SendToDataLayerThread("/message_path", message).start();
    }

    // Disconnect from the data layer when the Activity stops
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (null != googleClient && googleClient.isConnected()) {
            googleClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    // Placeholders for required connection callbacks
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) { }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

    class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread {
        String path;
        String message;

        // Constructor to send a message to the data layer
        SendToDataLayerThread(String p, String msg) {
            path = p;
            message = msg;
        }

        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleClient).await();
            for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleClient, node.getId(), path, message.getBytes()).await();
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.v("myTag", "Message: {" + message + "} sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
                }
                else {
                    // Log an error
                    Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send Message");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(getConnectedNodesResult -> {
            List<Node> nodes = getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes();
            if(nodes.size() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this,"You are not connected to any mobile device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setButtonStatus(true);
            } else {
                for (Node node : nodes) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "WEAR sending " + message + " to " + node);
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), message, payload).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "WEAR Result " + sendMessageResult.getStatus());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
```

Try this code to send the details from watch to mobile after connection established.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. This code didn't work for me =( Sending from my phone to my watch works fine. But sending something back is not working